# duvida referente um select dinamico

Tags: php, mysql

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho uma tabela no banco com as seguintes especificações.

```
ID | Produto | Qtdade | valor unitário de venda
--------------------------------------
1  | ABC     | 5000   | 10
2  | ABC     | 2000   | 9.5
3  | ABC     | 3000   | 11
```

A partir dessa tabela eu preciso fazer uma venda, na qual tenho que pegar sempre o primeiro, quando acabar a quantidade do primeiro dai pego o seguinte.
Então vamos supor que a venda que vou fazer seja de 8000 unidades, tenho que listar o pedido da seguinte forma:

```
PRODUTO  |  QUANTIDADE  |  VALOR TOTAL
ABC      | 5000         | 50000
ABC      | 2000         | 19000
ABC      | 1000         | 11000
```

Alguem pode me sugerir uma maneira de como fazer isso?

parte do código

```
$pedido = 8000; // (veio da quantidade da tabela de pedido)

$sql_pedido = 'SELECT * FROM estoque';
$busca_pedido = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql_pedido);

while ($linha_pedido = mysqli_fetch_object($busca_pedido)) {

    if ($pedido > 0) {
    $quant = $linha_pedido->quantidade;
    $valor = $linha_pedido->valorUnit;
    $pedido = $pedido - $linha_pedido->quantidade;
    $total = $quant*$valor;
    echo "$quant - R$ $valor ... Total em R$ $total<br>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa fazer algo como abaixo, extraído de [SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7098274/1997073):

```
SELECT *, @TOTAL := @TOTAL + quantidade AS total
FROM tabela1, (SELECT @TOTAL := 0) t
WHERE @TOTAL <= 8000
```

Mas veja que a consulta acima não retorna exatamente o que você precisa, pois ela seleciona a ultima linha com a quantidade total disponível no item, totalizando na coluna `total` 10000 ao invés de 8000.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que isso já te ajude, pois basta você tratar do lado do `php` para obter o que você precisa. No link que passei acima tem mais exemplos de como fazer o que você precisa.

Comment: sou meio leigo, estou aprendendo o php, mas como trataria essa questão no php? no baixaria essa parcial de valores?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ordenar os pedidos com a consulta SQL com `ORDER BY nome_do_compo DESC`

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_compra = 'o id da compra' ORDER BY quantidate DESC;
```

o sql acima ordena os produtos pelo campo 'quantidade' em ordem decrescente, ao invers de `DESC` voce pode usar `ASC` que deixa em ordem crescente.

Assim os registros já vem no ordem de imprimir na tela.

Uma leitura complementar
https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/order_by.php

Para poder manipular os valores você pode fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
$lista = [
        [1,"ABC",5000,10],
        [2,"ABC",2000,9.5],
        [3,"ABC",3000,11]
    ];

    $valorTotal = 8000;
    $valor = 0;

    foreach($lista as $key => $linha){
        // verifica se a soma passa do valor total 
        if($valor + $linha[2] < $valorTotal){
            $valor =  $valor + $linha[2];
            // zera o valor desse registro
            $lista[$key][2] = 0;
        }else{
            // ve a diferença dos valores
            $debito = $valorTotal - $valor;
            // debita apenas a diferença
            $saldoTranspor = $linha[2] - $debito;

            $lista[$key][2]  = $saldoTranspor ;
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($lista);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Assim só precisa fazer uma nova query para atualizar o banco

Comment: a questão da ordem ok, porem como pegar a quantidade que preciso no código, por exemplo ali o item 3 tem 3000, e ali vou precisar pegar só 1000 dele. Como seria isso em php?

Comment: entendi agora, vou editar a resposta

Comment: Como gero esse array desse jeito pegando os dados do banco?

Comment: Como esta vindo do seu banco ?

Comment: Faço um select * from tabela.... ele me trás já em sequência por causa da id que eh incremental... dai eu puxo quantidade e o valor das entradas... porém não consigo limitar e exibir o valor até chegar na quantidade correta

Comment: da um print_r() na variável que retorna e posta aqui

Comment: editei na minha postagem o codigo que uso para listar os quantidade, valor, e valor total porem não consigo descontar da quantidade do ultimo item no caso